# How to make the transparent parts of a sprite also clickable using a Raycast

Tags: unity

I have been making using the following code to add mouse clicks to my game objects.

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
    if ((hit.collider != null && hit.collider.gameObject.name == gameObject.name)
    )
    {

    //do something here
}
```

I have a game object which I made using a sprite with transparent areas. I would like the transparent areas to also be recognized as the game object being clicked. I am not sure if this can be achieved using a raycast. If not, I am open to other ways of achieving the same result.

Comment: There's a hint there in your code. `hit.collider`... aha! The Sprite must have a Collider2D component attached! What options do the various Collider2D components expose for you to customize the shape you get?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks, I managed to solve it with help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111821/unity3d-how-to-detect-click-within-an-area